# CoffeeScript code-complete for Web IDE

Tags: coffeescript, ace-editor

Is there a web based code-complete API/IDE for coffee script?

Ace Editor and CodeMirror have good syntax highlighting and lint-based syntax support, and what I would like to add to my app ([Node-WebKit-REPL](https://github.com/o2platform/nwr)) is code-complete support

Comment: Although I voted for your question to be closed, I think you can try Jetbrains Webstorm.

Comment: Why closed, it's quite an important feature to have for web based code editors? And yes I have and use WebStorm, but the point here is to have a web based editor with code complete (ideally an FOSS one like Ace or CodeMirror)

Comment: Well yes it is an important feature, but anyways according to the documentation reference ( [exactly point 4](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ] this topic is out of StackOverflow. You might ask on some other stackexchange websites.

Comment: OK, so if I rename the question to "I'm trying to add code complete to an CoffeeScript IDE, but can't find a good API', would that make it better? This is the kind of problem that one shouldn't really try to solve at first (i.e. too complex with no need to re-invent the wheel)

Comment: The answers will be opinionated. Go to the meta site and ask why. Here is a good example http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately neither CodeMirror nor Ace have autocompleters specially for coffeescript, but they both have an api to add a completer.

here's a simple example to show how do it for ace

```js
var lang = require("ace/lib/lang")
var languageTools = require("ace/ext/language_tools")
editor = ace.edit("editor")
editor.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true, // this does not work very well atm
  mode: "ace/mode/coffee"
})
var evalCompleter = {
  getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {          
    var completions = [];
    var props = Object.keys(window);
    props.forEach(function(key){      
      completions.push({
        value: key,        
        meta: 'window',
        type: 'eval',
        score: 1000
      });
    })
    callback(null, completions)
  },
  getDocTooltip: function(item) {
    if (item.type == 'eval' && !item.docHTML) {
      var o = window[item.value]
      var type = typeof o
      item.docHTML = "<b>" + type  + "</b><br>"  
         + lang.escapeHTML(o + "");
    }
  }
}
editor.completers = [evalCompleter, languageTools.keyWordCompleter,
  languageTools.snippetCompleter, languageTools.textCompleter
];
```

of course in a real application you will need some kind of parser to get the expression before the . to evaluate

http://sevin7676.github.io/Ace.Tern/demo.html also can be useful.

Comment: For reference here is the GitHub Issue that is tracking this https://github.com/o2platform/nwr/issues/29